# Are decimals without leading zeros valid JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Given the JSON document

```
{"percentageAmount": .01}
```

Running it by JSONLint.com results in the error:

```
Parse error on line 2:
..."percentageAmount": .01}
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

On the other hand, this is valid:

```
{"percentageAmount": 0.01}
```

The code is parsed correctly if assigned to a variable as a JavaScript literal, but of course there are many things that are OK for JavaScript variables that aren't JSON spec.

Why is this against JSON spec?

Comment: Look at the `number` production at http://www.json.org/

Comment: since JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation so it is a subset of javascript it should validate it normally. Maybe because json is used to exhange data through servers side (php, asp) where .01 values are not valid

Comment: In general, JSON is a much-simplified subset of Javascript literal notation.

Comment: @albanx — Since the set of numbers that include `0.1` is a subset of the set of numbers that include `.1` and `0.1`, being a subset does not mean that `.1` is valid. JSON is (in the right context) valid JavaScript. The reverse is not necessarily true.

Comment: just an FYI: similarly `{percentageAmount: 0.01}` is valid javascript, but jsonlint rejects it as invalid JSON.

Comment: @Quentin what ? nevermind. in fact the matter is how json whas defined, but as you say in your answer the author does not have documented that, and I think it is so because json is used to exchange data betwen more languages

Comment: It is not only the Javascript that uses the JSON. I wonder how can people create this kind of errors when every platform has functions to encode and decode JSON...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Are decimals without leading zeros valid JSON?

From [the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159):

```
  number = [ minus ] int [ frac ] [ exp ]

  decimal-point = %x2E       ; .

  digit1-9 = %x31-39         ; 1-9

  e = %x65 / %x45            ; e E

  exp = e [ minus / plus ] 1*DIGIT

  frac = decimal-point 1*DIGIT

  int = zero / ( digit1-9 *DIGIT )

  minus = %x2D               ; -

  plus = %x2B                ; +

  zero = %x30                ; 0
```

The only part of a number that is mandatory is `int` which is defined as `zero` or `1-9` followed by any number of digits.

So JSON Lint is correct.

> Why is this against JSON spec?

As far as I know, the author's reasons for defining it that way are not documented anywhere.

Answer (score 14):

## Nope.

According to the [railroad diagram for numbers at JSON.org](http://json.org), numbers with fractional values must have digits before the decimal point:

[image: Diagram showing that numbers with fraction parts must have a digit before the decimal point.]

Comment: I love these diagrams. This provides the answer.

Comment: If I'm reading that correctly, a leading 0 followed by a digit is also invalid:  i.e.  000.1234 and 0123.45 are invalid.  Correct?  Not that I would deliberately code input that way, but their spec is bad.

Comment: Well neither of those numbers are valid in JavaScript (SyntaxError) so it seems reasonable to me.

Comment: r`^\.[0-9]+$` should definitely be supported, though. There is no reason not to support it.

Comment: Perhaps what was shown was an older version of the diagram? The one shown now shows that after 0 the only characters allowed directly after a zero are a decimal point or e or E or nothing. So any digit after 0 would be invalid