# SteamVR HDK JSON Error

Tags: json, virtual-reality, steam, openvr

I'm about at my wit's end right now dealing with the GUI. I'm making a controller to track in VR for a school project, and I am at the stage where I am running simulations to verify my JSON. I had to hand make it because our group already decided on sensor placements, so I followed the reference controller template. Unfortunately, there is a perpetual error at [34, 33] that I can't figure out. I will post a piece of the code here:

"plus_z" : [ 0, 1, 0 ], "position" : [ -0.05221, 0, 0 ] }, "render_model" : "KNIFE_MODEL.obj", "head" :

These are lines 31-35. My error is a leading decimal, however when I've run it through several online JSON validators, my code is valid. Earlier today, the model visualized in OpenScad several times, however my sensor orientation was wrong so when I fixed the coordinates, the GUI gave me the same error as usual. No matter what version I reverted to I got the same error.

Comment: What is the error? What is the code that generates the error?

Comment: The error is "Leading Decimal at [34,33]"

Comment: I don't think you've given us enough information to solve your problem. If you edit your question adding your *actual* data and the code that causes the problem, your question will be bumped back to the top of the list and you might get some helpful answers.

Comment: Take a look at this question, it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898431/are-decimals-without-leading-zeros-valid-json